# Xcode ask for a registered device in the Members Centre

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have started looking at swift so I downloaded Xcode 7.3.1 and fired up the app. When creating a project I added my apple account in the identity section and clicked in Fix Issue to provision my profile and I get an error saying:

No Device:
Creating a profile requires having a device registered in the Member Center.

If I go to the Members Centre I can see where you add a device. If I go to my apple account I can see all my devices (Laptop, iPhone and iPad).

How do you register a device in the Members Centre?

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin, i fear this is the wrong place for this question ;;.)

Comment: I am also looks at the apple forums. Stack is always my default place to go though :-)

Comment: @Kevin my smiley was bad. Should be ;-) and not ;;.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have an Apple developer account you should be able to just connect your device via USB when using Xcode and everything is all automatic.

In the status bar at the top you can see Xcode says t's building profiles. The device gets added automatically.

Comment: Hi, in the initial page after creating a project in the Identity section there is a warning saying "No Provisioning profiles found" and a button saying "Fix Issue". When I click on it that's when I get the message. Do I need to have a device plugged in at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to pay the $99 fee to add devices. Or at least that's what I understand from the Apple Forum.

screen shot is below...

[image]

Comment: No you do not need to pay to add devices.

Comment: ok, that's good news. So is there a different place to register devices for development (i.e. not my apple account) id so where. I can't see it in the Members Centre

Comment: Screenshot added above

Comment: I can't seem to add devices to the Members Center or even find the Members Center. Perhaps apple changed its accessibility to people who are not part of the developer program?